# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] not recognized

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-301

I have this simple statement that checks if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` returns the same value of the variable `$C['ST__URL']`. If not it does a 301 redirect.
Today we had a downtime because the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` did not match with the `$C['ST__URL']` variable.

The downtime was caused by a forced 301 redirect falling into a continuous loop, so the reason must be the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` not been recognized.

The `$C['ST__URL']` was correctly filled, so I am wondering which can be the cause of the downtime? An Apache temporary issue? A different configuration in the DNS zone?

```
$url = parse_url($C['ST__URL']);

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!=$url['host']) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: '.$C['ST__URL'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try a var_dump on each variable to see what they contain?

Comment: Well, you would not get a HTTP_HOST if the client doesn’t send a host name with the request, but reaches the server via IP. As for the “downtime” you speak of, what exactly do you mean by that? “Normal” HTTP clients just follow a certain number of redirects before they cancel the request, and I don’t see how a single client not sending a host header could cause a “downtime” (unless you neglected to mention certain special conditions).

Comment: You are basically saying: I have no idea what happened, how can I make it so that it doesn't happen again. First figure out what happens, then fix it. Also: why would you need this. As you have demonstrated, this is dangerous code to randomly have around. Serve a header if you need to (the moment you fill st__URL maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

I would first check in the apache request logs.

You say "the reason must be the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] not been recognized. " but you don't really know that at all, do you? Why Not? You don't have any record of it. Now that you know this is an issue, set up to log it should it happen again:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!=$url['host']) {

    error_log("Invoking redirect: server host $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] mismatch with url $url.\r\n"),3,"/var/log/http301redirect.log");

    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: '.$C['ST__URL'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

That is just a sample message, you would want to datestamp and customize the log message.